# Dynamic Sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe of grocery transactions containing ['customer_id', 'date', 'item_code', and 'amount'].

I want to group multiple transactions from the same day into 1 transaction, with a sum of those individual transactions. For example, if I bought 3 items on 1-1-16, for $5, $10, and $15 each, I want that to be represented as a single row with a value of $30.

That part is a simple groupby

```
df.groupby(['customer_id', 'date'])['amount'].sum()
```

My problem is that I want to create a new column called "transaction_type" that assigns a code ('grpd') to a row ***if that row was grouped***, and the corresponding value of item_code ***if it was not grouped***.

So if I purchased 3 items on 1-1-16, but purchased a single new item on 1-2-16, I want my customer_id to show 2 rows in the dataframe. One for 1-1-16 with the custom 'grpd' value in the new transaction_type column, and one for 1-2-16 with the original value from the item_code column reproduced into the transaction_type column. So my dataframe would look like this in the end for my transactions:

```
customer_id     date    transaction_type   amount
  4231         1-1-16        grpd           $30
  4231         1-2-16        candy          $5
```

Comment: Can you post also a source data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':['4231']*4,'date':['1-1-2016','1-1-2016','1-1-2016','1-2-2016'],'items':['gum','candy','soda','candy'],'amount':[9,11,10,5]})
```

Input:

```
   amount customer_id      date  items
0       9        4231  1-1-2016    gum
1      11        4231  1-1-2016  candy
2      10        4231  1-1-2016   soda
3       5        4231  1-2-2016  candy
```

Use `.agg`, `np.where`, and `size`:

```
df_out = (df.groupby(['customer_id','date'])
    .agg({'items': lambda x: np.where(x.size > 1,'grpd',x.min()),'amount':'sum'})
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'items':"transaction_type"}))
```

Output:

```
  customer_id      date  amount transaction_type
0        4231  1-1-2016      30             grpd
1        4231  1-2-2016       5            candy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby the `transaction_type` too:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'customer_id', 'transaction_type'])['amount'].sum()
```